# Design don't appear on Debug

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcpclient

I'm creating a C# Socket Server, it already works, but now, when I press "Start" the "design" of the application doesn't load, it's not visible.

The socket server is running correcty (I see it working in the output window), I don't see any kind of error. I start deleting parts of the code, and the design stops being visible after this line:

```
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
...
```

If I remove from this line to the end, it appear again.

What's going on? (sorry for my bad english)

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    start();
}

private void start() {

    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);

    server.Start();

    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

    Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");

}
```

I Think the problem is that the load is interrupted while the socket is working waiting for connections.

I'm trying to execute "start()" function on Form1_Shown but it does not work.

How can I be sure to start the socket server after the Form is full loaded?

Comment: Please show your complete code

Comment: Done, I just edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`server.AcceptTcpClient()` is a blocking call and you are making it on the UI thread. You have a few options, here they are in the order I would do them.

Make the function you are calling it from async and use [AcceptTcpClientAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
//Event handlers like `Load` are the only place you are allowed to do "async void"
private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await start();
}

private async Task start() {

    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);

    server.Start();

    TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();

    Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");

}
```

If you can't use async/await because of the version of .NET you are targeting use [BeginAcceptTcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.beginaccepttcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) to have a callback accept the client instead.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    start();
}

private void start() {

    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);

    server.Start();

    server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(AcceptClient, server);

}

private void AcceptClient(IAsyncResult result)
{
    var server = (TcpListener)result.AsyncState;
    TcpClient client = server.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);

    Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");
}
```

Or one other option is put the code you currently have on a background thread via a `Task.Run(` or similar. However, I really would not recommend this approach, you tie up a thread just waiting for a new connection, the framework already provides better ways to do this without a thread by using async/await or the begin/end pair.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => start());
}

private void start() {

    TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);

    server.Start();

    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

    Console.WriteLine("Client connected.");

}
```

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much Scott, It works with BeginAcceptTcpClient.